# Mongo $text search not working on nested object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo_search_problem');

var test = new Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  level: {
    two: { type: String, required: true }
  }
});

test.index({
  text: 'text',
  'level.two': 'text'
});

var Model = mongoose.model('tests', test);

Model.find({ $text: { $search: 'two' } }, function(err, result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

This is the document

```
{
  "text" : "text",
  "level" : {
    "two" : "two"
  }
}
```

It will return nothing if I search `two`, but if I search `text` instead it will return the document.

Why won't this work on nested object?

Comment: To run :
copy the first part in an `index.js` file, `npm install mongoose`. Then create a DB called `mongo_search_problem` and add the document to a model called `tests` and run `node index.js`

Comment: Mongo version is 3.4.6 on a mac